# Calculation of a picture resize compare to an available space

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's assume I have a picture and I need to put it into a square. But in some cases, the picture is too big, so I need to change its size so it will be fit to the square.

The algorithm should calculate and return by how much I need to reduce its size. The function get the pic height, width, the square height and square width. It'll return a number that says by how much I need to reduce, keeping the original width to height ratio.

This is my solution, and I am not sure if I cover all cases:

```
double CalcPicSize(double picWidth, double  picHeight, double  sqWidth, double  sqHeight )
{
    var widthRatio, heightRatio;
    if (picWidth <= 0 || picHeight <= 0 || sqWidth <= 0 || sqHeight <= 0)
        return -1;

    if (picWidth == null || picHeight == null || sqWidth == null || sqHeight == null)
        return -1;

    if(picWidth <= sqWidth && picHeight <= sqHeight)
        return 1;

    widthRatio = picWidth / sqWidth;
    heightRatio = picHeight / sqHeight;
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
        return widthRatio;
    return heightRatio;
}
```

Comment: this look better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is `square height` = `height of the square` .. or `height*height` ? (coz imho.. square have equal height & width)